# float div next to 100% width div

Tags: html, css

I would like to position a div next to a div with contents of `width: 100%`. So the markup is:

```
<div id="left_sidebar" style="float: left; height: 100%; width: 150px;"></div>
<div id="outer_wrapper" style="position: relative; float: left;"></div>
```

pretty much everything in `#outer_wrapper` has a width of 100%. Unfortunatly it does not work.

I made a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cm9qxbt8/)

Comment: 100% is 100%, which is the whole viewport, you can't have 100% + 150px. Is `#outer_wrapper` supposed to have content that fills it entirely or itself has 100% width?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Makes no sense to have more than 100% of width

Comment: I want to have a left div outside of `outer_wrapper` which pushes the hole div to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about :

```css
#left {
    width: 150px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="right">
  content here
    <div id="left"></div>
  more content here
</div>
```

**SECOND OPTION :**

remove the width and the float property of the `.right` div and give it 150px left margin :

```css
#left {
    width: 150px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left:150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

Comment: because I need the left div to push all contents of right to the side

Comment: @supersize Check the updated snippet, the content of right div is pushed to the right.

Comment: Its a good answer, I think the `left` within `right` might confuse

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hasecbinusr/cm9qxbt8/2/

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   var rightWidth = $(window).width - $('#left').width();
   $('#right').width(rightWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<div style="padding-left:150px; position:relative;width:100%;">
    <div id="outer_wrapper" style="position: relative; width:100%">this is 100%</div>
    <div id="left_sidebar" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:150px;">this is 150 pixels wide</div>
</div>
```

The idea is to have the outer-most div a left padding of `150px` so that the first child div will be rendered `150px` away from the border. Then add another div that will become the left container by using an absolute position and force it to be rendered as if it is the first.